# How will several Cs and one F affect my chances of gettting into a PhD program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, engineering

I'm a junior chemical engineering major who is interested in getting a PhD in chemical engineering. However, my grades in nearly all of my chemical engineering courses have been about a C and I've also made a D in one of my chemical  engineering courses. I've made Cs in one of intro chemical engineering courses focusing on mass and energy balances as well as statics,quantitative methods, and physical chemistry. I've made a D and have to retake my Properties of Materials class. Ive made As and Bs in Im planning on retaking some of these classes to improve my grades but I'm  still worried about how these grades will be precieved by a graduate admissions committee in the long run. How badly do these grades affect my chances to get into a PhD program? Do I have a chance at this point? What should someone in my situation do going forward to become a more competitive applicant for graduate school?

Comment: It will be pretty hard. In the US it might not be impossible, but you would need other things to show your knowledge and potential. Pretty steep climb.

Comment: You've made As and Bs in what? I think you forgot to type some words

Comment: Which country are you in.